Security Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL.. and signalrHubConnection.start()
I was using qt 5 and i upgraded to qt6. I got to know that QtWebengine is replaced with QtWebEngineQuick. Now i have a server which runs in QT and a client which runs on angular connects to it. I have verified the connection and the client is getting connected. I used to load index.html and after that my application front page used to load.
Now after upgrade ,once index.html is loaded, i am getting a black screen. The only thing which changed in my application is the QT upgrade.
I am getting below errors and to be honest i am clueless. Please help me in giving insight what could be going wrong
2024_04_04 12_22_35_897 [INF]: Hiding the splash screen
2024_04_04 12_22_36_063 [WRN]: HttpErrorResponse Status: 0
2024_04_04 12_22_36_302 [WRN]: [2024-04-04T06:52:36.291Z] Warning: Error from HTTP request. 0: .
2024_04_04 12_22_36_330 [N/A]: [2024-04-04T06:52:36.325Z] Error: Failed to complete negotiation with the server: Error
2024_04_04 12_22_36_463 [N/A]: [2024-04-04T06:52:36.466Z] Error: Failed to start the connection: Error
2024_04_04 12_22_36_547 [WRN]: wake - this.signalrHubConnection.start() error is Error Thu, 04 Apr 2024 06:52:36 GMT

some issue in signalrhub connection started after this where the signalrhub is not able to start.
I tried switching Signalr versions, but it didn't work.
